# Upgrading to Xcode 5.0 introduced hundreds of the same warnings "Letter Spacing Adjustment on iOS versions prior to 6.0"

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I have a project previously in Xcode 4.0. It runs without any warnings or errors. I just moved it to the Xcode 5.0. After getting rid of tons of errors, I'm now left with hundreds of the same warning:
"Attribute Unavailable. Letter Spacing Adjustment on iOS versions prior to 6.0."
The warning appears all in my xib files.
Anyone has any idea of what causes the warning and how I can get rid of them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Worked out a solution.
Attributes inspector -> uncheck Tighten Letter Spacing under Autoshrink. Re-run. The warnings should be gone.